# Unable to cover get set in apex test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am unable to cover the following class get set method. Need help in creating test class

```
public class Aresult{

    public class Parent {
        public String type {get; set;}
        public String id {get; set;}
        public String sequence_id {get; set;}
        public String etag {get; set;}
        public String name {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Please suggest

```
@isTest 
public class CirriusGetItemsResultTest {
    public static void myUnitTest(){
        Aresult.parent a = new Aresult.parent();
        a.type='hello';
        a.id='hello';
        a.sequence_id ='hello';
        a.etag ='hello';
        a.name ='hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the test code you have written so far for this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test method should use **testmethod** keyword or alternatively annotated with "**@isTest**" .You class is annotated with @isTest but not your test method .

Check the screenshot of test run result  screen when your test methods are properly annotated and when test methods are not

[image]

Clearly the one with annotated properly runs and provides necessary coverage

The below test code covers the class 100%

```
@isTest 
 public class CirriusGetItemsResultTest {
    public static testmethod void myUnitTest(){
     Aresult.parent a = new Aresult.parent();
     a.type='hello';
     a.id='hello';
     a.sequence_id ='hello';
     a.etag ='hello';
     a.name ='hello';
   }
}
```

Also kindly note that purpose of test code is not just test coverage .Your wrapper might be invoked form your Visualforce controller or trigger or webservices etc and invoking those methods should automatically cover the wrappwr class

Comment: To add to the answer, this pattern to test in the answer is only needed when the sole purpose of the class is to deserialize a string into. IIRC just getting the values does not cover the lines. (I will have to test again - if I am wrong please ignore). Otherwise line Mohith  said your normal code flow should cover the class. If it does not then is the code really needed?

Comment: Good points .On assigning values ,it actually covers .I have tested the code in my org. Again lot of assumptions here .Will wait for user to comment on why he needed a test code and purpose of wrapper class

Comment: Ok, added the test coverage as an answer. Seems either getters not covering was a bug in earlier API's or one of a thousand things including my memory on the exact scenario. Either way posted results to help support your answer

Comment: Just to extend this answer, the main purpose of your tests is to *verify business logic*. Coverage is just a by product. If you focus on covering the behaviour, code coverage will come automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Mohith Shrivastava's answer....

Looks like in this case getters did cover it although I know I have seen cases where it did not (could have been a number of thing though).

In the API 38.0 here are the results:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class junkTest { //0 of 5 lines covered
    public static testmethod void deserializeTest() {
        String t = '{"type":"t","sequence_id":"si","name":"n","id":"i","etag":"et"}';
        junkClass.Parent j = (junkClass.Parent) json.deserialize(t, junkClass.Parent.class);
        system.debug(t);
    }

    public static testmethod void deserializeAndGetTest() { //5 of 5 lines covered
        String t = '{"type":"t","sequence_id":"si","name":"n","id":"i","etag":"et"}';
        junkClass.Parent j = (junkClass.Parent) json.deserialize(t, junkClass.Parent.class);
        system.debug(j.type);
        system.debug(j.id);
        system.debug(j.sequence_id);
        system.debug(j.etag);
        system.debug(j.name);

    }


    public static testmethod void constructTest() { //5 of 5 line covered
        junkClass.parent p = New junkClass.parent();
        p.type = 't';
        p.id = 'i';
        p.sequence_id = 'si';
        p.etag = 'et';
        p.name = 'n';

    }
}
```

Now, off to delete these example classes so I do not accidentally package and release it by mistake :)